# How to display a field like this using HTML5 and

Tags: php, html

[image: img]

i want a field like this inside a form. The datas inside this field are retrieved from database.

Comment: **Select2**, **Chosen**, **FCBK**  .... Or make your own.

Comment: use tagsinput jquery plugin

Comment: http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/    and  https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/tags/

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing is you need a plugin named `select2`.

Note that when tagging is enabled the user can select from pre-existing options or create a new tag by picking the first choice, which is what the user has typed into the search box so far.

Select2 can be used to quickly set up fields used for tagging. The `Tagging support`.

**Javascript code**

```
$(".your-class").select2({
  tags: true
})
```

The example: [here](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags)

Download the CDN from [here](https://select2.github.io/)

You can also show data from database here.

Try this, and let me know is it work for you or not.